# Is there a way to tell when a Widget is shown with GWT?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'd like to respond to an even whenever my widget is made visible on a page done with GWT and UI Binder.

Is there anything similar to the `onAttach()` event handler (which fires when the widget is added to the DOM), pertaining to when the widget is actually made visible?

I'd like to be able to handle the even when the widget is shown because there are a few different ways of making it visible, and I'd like a single place on the widget itself that can handle this event.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The widget should be visible once added to the DOM unless you've intentionally hidden it (i.e. with CSS or hid it behind another widget). Normally, onAttached() means its on the page. If you're using CSS classes to make it visible, write a *setVisible(boolean isVisible)* method to your widget and set the visibility class this way. If you have it behind another widget (i.e. in layers) then you'll need to write your only logic to determine when it's visible.

Comment: Right, the problem isn't that the widget isn't visible... it's that I'd like to be able to do things from within the widget when it's visibility changes (ex: check user's logged in status).  I guess the answer is there's no way of doing this out of the box with GWT's controls.

Comment: @cuga I'm not aware of any such browser event. You'd have to set the event in GWT yourself and listen for it AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, I have faced the same problem before. What I did was override the `setVisible(boolean visible)` method in the widget, then perform whatever I needed to do:

```
@Override
public void setVisible(boolean isVisible) {
    super.setVisible(isVisible);
            if(isVisible) {
                // Do whatever you need to do with your widget
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no browser event for this, but you could try this:

With your widget you could check the elements `getLeftOffset` (or similar method), if you get a positive value, you could fire your method, and set a flag to indicate that your `onVisible()` method had fired.

Then once the `getLeftOffset` returns a 0 you could reset your flag, ready to fire your event again.